# JSON Date parameter passed to MVC Action is always null

Tags: jquery, json, datetime, asp.net-mvc-2, types

I have a range of parameters that are passed via jQuery Ajax to an MVC JsonResult action.  For the most part, these arrive successfully, but there is a Date value that is not arriving at all.

What considerations / formats do I need to use - or what approaches do I need to take - in order to get this date to arrive successfully?

```
...other code ...
myStory.Deadline = new Date($('#story-deadline').val());

$.ajax({
    url: '/Project/' + action[2] + '/AddStory',
    data: { Summary: myStory.Summary, Size: myStory.Size, Priority: myStory.Priority,
            Owner: myStory.Owner, Deadline: myStory.Deadline },
    dataType: 'json',
    traditional: true,
    type: 'POST',
...the rest of the code...
```

The JsonResult action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddStory(int projectid, Story story)
{
...some code that doesn't have a DateTime object to work with...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to serialize/desirealize the ASP.NET MVC data. If use `/Date(utcDate)/` format for the `Date` data type. Try to use

```
'"\\/Date(' + myStory.Deadline.getTime() + ')\\/"'
```

or

```
var d = myStory.Deadline;
var dateForMS = '"\\/Date(' +
        Date.UTC (d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(),
                  d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(),
                  d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds(),
                  d.getUTCMilliseconds()) + ')\\/"'
```

You can also just use `Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` from `MicrosoftAjax.js` to serialize `Deadline` or any other `Date` type.

**UPDATED**: Probably you should use `'\/Date('` and `')\/'` instead of `'"\\/Date('` and `')\\/"'`. All depends on where you will insert the string.

**UPDATED 2**: Now I have it! ASP.NET MVC is used mostly for the posting Form fields per Ajax. On the server side will be just used `Parse` method for every type to convert the posted parameter to the type. So one can use any string format which are supported by [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx#remarksToggle). For example you can use ISO 8601 format like '2010-08-29T13:15:00.0000000Z'. To do this in modern browsers (firefox, chrome) one can use `toISOString()` function. To be more independend one can implement data conversion like described in http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=503:

```
var d = new Date($('#story-deadline').val())
//var d = new Date(); // get the date. Here we use just Now.
var dAsISOString;
if ($.isFunction(d.toISOString)) {
    //alert("internal toISOString are used!");
    dAsISOString = d.toISOString();
}
else {
    dAsISOString = d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + padzero(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' +
                   padzero(d.getUTCDate()) + 'T' + padzero(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' +
                   padzero(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + padzero(d.getUTCSeconds())+'.'+
                   pad2zeros(d.getUTCMilliseconds()) + 'Z';
}
var myStory = { Summary: 'Test description', Size: 8, Dedline: dAsISOString };
$.ajax({
    url: '/Project/1/AddStory',
    data: { Summary: myStory.Summary, Size: myStory.Size, Dedline: myStory.Dedline },
    dataType: 'json',
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I've tried both your original formatting suggestion and the updated one and both are still arriving as null.  They are being posted correctly, though: Deadline "/Date(1283169600000)/"

Comment: It seems that one should test the problem with the source code of MVC (see http://weblogs.asp.net/jacqueseloff/archive/2010/04/20/mvc-2-source-code-released-to-microsoft-reference-server.aspx and http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742). If you will have any results let me know.

Comment: it works for me only in case I manually serialize data as json.  **data: JSON.stringify(params),**

Comment: @vsapiha: The problem that all depend from the configuration parameters which one uses and from the version of ASP.NET MVC which you use. The code which I posted in my answer I tested before. If in your configuration `data: JSON.stringify(params)` works: fine! Then use it.

Comment: @Oleg its better to add a filter here which convert json to object, reason i can't use other json provider like newtonsoft which are much matured than javascript serializer , what you suggest

Comment: toISOString() saved me +1