# Inline jqGrid editing "Request Error"

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423035/editing-jqgrid-and-sending-data-to-net-mvc-webservice) I had earlier this week.

I was able to get the form edit features to work just fine.  Now I wanted to take it a step further and see if I can get the inline editing working.  I used the code from the examples that adds the 3 buttons; E S C.  E)dit and C)ancel works just great.  The S)ave row function does not.  Is it possible to use the same code for the form edit to work with the inline edits?  Or is it one or the other?

I seem to be in the same boat I was with my original question.  I can see the data being sent and it's not in JSON format.  It looks like: **Id=823&Step_Number=1&Step_Description=xxx.&oper=edit&id=1**.  The error that I'm receiving goes like this:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service. The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

I've looked into the ajaxRowOptions but that doesn't seem to change anything.  Doesn't mean I had it in the right position.

> ```
> [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Save/JSA", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
> public string UpdateJSADetail(int Id, string Step_Number, string Step_Description, string oper, string id)
> ```

```
...
onclickSubmitLocal = function (options, postdata) {                    
},
editSettings = {
    recreateForm: true,
    width: 400,
    jqModal: false,
    reloadAfterSubmit: false,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    savekey: [true, 13],
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
},
addSettings = {
    recreateForm: true,
    jqModal: false,
    reloadAfterSubmit: false,
    savekey: [true, 13],
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
};

$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'FileServices/GetList/JSA',
    edit: {
        mtype: "POST"
    },
    editurl: 'FileServices/Save/JSA',
    datatype: 'local',
    gridComplete: function () {
        var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var cl = ids[i]; 
            be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').editRow('" + cl + "');\" />";
            se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').saveRow('" + cl + "');\" />"; 
            ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').restoreRow('" + cl + "');\" />";
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be + se + ce });
        }

        $("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam', {}).trigger("reloadGrid");
    },
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        var det = $("#details");
        $("#list").setGridWidth(det.width() - 18, true);
    },
    colNames: ['Actions', 'Id', 'Step Number', 'Step Description', 'Hazards', 'Controls', 'Sequence'],
    colModel: [
      { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 75, sortable: false },
      { name: 'Id', editable: true, index: 'Id', width: 30, sortable: false, hidden: true },
      { name: 'Step_Number', editable: true, index: 'Step_Number', align: 'center', width: 50, fixed: true, resizable: false, sortable: false, title: false, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="font-weight: bold: true; white-space: normal; vertical-align: middle;' } },
      { name: 'Step_Description', editable: true, index: 'Step_Description', edittype: 'textarea', editoptions: { rows: '4', cols: '40' }, sortable: false, width: 400, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal; vertical-align: top;' } },
      { name: 'Hazards', index: 'Hazards', width: 200, sortable: false, formatter: JSAHazardFormatter, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal; vertical-align: top;' } },
      { name: 'Controls', index: 'Controls', width: 200, sortable: false, cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { return 'style="white-space: normal; vertical-align: top;' } },
      { name: 'Sequence', index: 'Sequence', width: 0, sortable: false, hidden: true }
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 50],
    sortname: 'Id',
    height: 'auto',
    rownumbers: true,
    autowidth: true,
    forceFit: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    hidegrid: false,
    caption: ''
}).navGrid("#pager", { add: false, edit: true, del: false, search: false }, editSettings, {}, {}, {}, {});

$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    recreateForm: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    serializeEditData: function (postData) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    }
});

var thegrid = $("#list");

for (var i = 0; i < data.details.length; i++) {
    thegrid.addRowData(i + 1, data.details[i]);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share the same code on the server side for both inline editing and form editing. The usage of `ajaxRowOptions` is the correct way to solve your problem. It should has at least `contentType: "application/json"`. Try to do following

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    ... // you current parameters
    ajaxRowOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    serializeRowData: function (data) {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    }
});
```

or you can set some jqGrid defaults with

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    ajaxRowOptions: { contentType: "application/json", type: "PUT", async: true },
    serializeRowData: function (data) {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    }
});
```

In the case you would not need to set the same settings in every grid which you use.

Of cause you should change the defaults **before** creating of the grid. Currently you use `$.extend($.jgrid.edit, ...` **after** creating of the grid which also not good, but can do work. The  `$.jgrid.defaults` you should change in any way before creating of the grid. Typically you place the setting of all you default settings in a separate JavaScript file which you included on all you pages which use jqGrid.

I recommended you in the comment **don't use `addRowData`** which make you code working slowly. Simple replacing of the `addRowData` in a loop *after* the grid already created to the additional parameter `data: data.details` will improve the performance. The usage of `getDataIDs` and the `for` loop over all rows makes you code more slowly. I recommend you to read [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912008/jqgrid-does-not-populate-with-data/3914796#3914796) which describes how to fill jqGrid with the data provided by WCF service.

Instead of the usage 'E', 'S', 'C' buttons you can use [formatter:'actions'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) (see [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196387/jqgrid-editactioniconscolumn-events/5204793#5204793) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622779/custom-jqgrid-post-action/6627201#6627201)). [One more old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303471/browser-memory-usage-comparison-inline-onclick-vs-using-jquery-bind/5305904#5305904) describe another approach to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you Oleg.  I think I've read just about every post you have written.  I double and triple check before I post my question.  I added the few lines you mentioned at the top and it worked right away.  I'm going to try the defaults part next; putting that code before my grid.  As for the addRowData problem, I'm still working with that.  I'm still new to jqGrid.  I'm chugging along slowly.  Once I get this part all situated, I will tackle removing addRowData.

Comment: @DrZ: You are welcome! About `addRowData` I suggest following: just add to jqGrid an additional parameter `data: data.details` and remove the `for` loop where you call `addRowData`. You will see that everything will still work, but work better and more quickly. Now the local data paging will work. If you will display more as 5 rows at once you can increase the value of `rowNum: 5` parameter.