# JSON date not posting to controller (KnockoutJS/JQuery, MVC 4 RC)

Tags: jquery, vb.net, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a KnockoutJS viewmodel which I'm posting to an MVC controller as a JSON object like so:

```
var dataObj = ko.toJSON(viewModel);
$.post(postURL, dataObj, callBackFunc);
```

The model itself has a date of birth field:
`dataObj.DOB`

However whenever my MVC controller receives it, the DOB field is always `#12:00:00 AM#` (VB.NET)

Here's my controller below:

```
<HttpPost()> _
    <AjaxOnly()> _
    Public Function PersonalDetails(PersonalInfo As DetailsViewModel.PersonalDetails)
        'clean the null values
        Dim newValues As Dictionary(Of String, String) = _getPropertyDict(PersonalInfo)
        Dim repo As New DetailsViewModelRepository()

    For Each entry In newValues
        repo.InsertUpdateField(PersonalInfo.MemberId, entry.Key, entry.Value)
    Next

    Return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Details/PersonalDetails.vbhtml", PersonalInfo)
End Function
```

How do I get it to receive the date properly?

Comment: Is the property named DOB on the PersonalDetails object?  Is this the only property that does not seem to get deserialized in the controller?  Is it only an issue with date fields or have you been able to do this with other date fields previously?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it doesn't work with any data members of type Date.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583252/json-date-parameter-passed-to-mvc-action-is-always-null

Comment: @Mike C Looks like it but trying `dataObj.DOB = '\\/Date(' + dataObj.DOB.getTime() + ')\\/';` doesn't solve the problem for me. I thought MVC 4 was supposed to use the JSON.NET parser by default?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, MVC4 only uses JSON.NET within the Web API, not standard controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked, just not sure about the range of browser compatibility:

`dataObj.DOB = dataObj.DOB.toISOString();`